# QPixmap load doesnt work

Tags: c++, qt4

I'm trying to put image to my form using QPixmap and QLabel. But i cant load image to QPixmap. Here is what i have:

```
qDebug() << QFile("C:/img.png").exists(); - true
qDebug() << map.load("C:/img.png"); - false
```

I have this file but still cant load it. I use Qt 4.8 with static linking.

Comment: Did you try it with other image files? Maybe there's something about that specific file, and Qt can't decode it for some reason (even if it opens in another program).

Comment: Yep, looks like there was something wrong with that image. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could possibly be with the particular file you're trying to load.

Try loading another file and see if you have the same problem.